# Table cell background bleeds through a table with rounded corners

Tags: html, css, css-tables

As can be seen on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFYvq/), in which a table is set with round corners (specifically the top-right and bottom-left), those corners are breached by their contained cell's background color.

I tried applying some `padding` to the table, but that didn't help. Is my only option to add an extra column and row and set their `background-color` to `transparent`?

How to fix this using CSS only (no added images or javascript)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the table's CSS rule to clip its inner content. The [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow) states that:

> The overflow CSS property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scroll bars or display overflow content of a block-level element.

As tables are [considered block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements), this rule applies.

To overcome inconsistencies with Gecko driven browsers (e.g. Firefox), apply `display: inline-block` as well.

---

See the [updated demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFYvq/20/).

Answer (score 2):

may be this option help you

```
table thead tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 1em 0 0;
}

table tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 1em;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZFYvq/10/

Also, instead of the pseudo classes can use the classes and add them to the desired cell

Comment: same issue with FF, but I like your css. more precise.

Comment: this solution is quite creative, but not very KISS. it is also error-prone; what happens if explicit font sizing is applied to the `td` elements elsewhere on the stylesheet? another thing, there's a thin gap between the `td`s and the table border that will be hard to fix.

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFYvq/37/)

You're better off wrapping the table in a `div` with the relevant border radius properties set, e.g:

```
div{
    border-top-right-radius: 1em; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

By setting the `display` property for the table to anything other than `table` you are breaking the specific layout rules which apply to `table` elements, which will produce often unforseen issues, like not working in IE. The above is the only truly cross browser semantic solution.

nb. To remove the thick border at the bottom of the table, add `border-bottom:none;` to the `div` class