# HTML Table (with width of 100%!) how to fill all the table width when inline-block is used

Tags: html, css

This is a follow-up of: [Table cell background bleeds through a table with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297153/table-cell-background-bleeds-through-a-table-with-rounded-corners) which answers similar question, but only for elements that are not "100% width".

I have a HTML table which has rounded corners and which TH elements have a background.
In IE11 this background does not fit (exceeds) the rounded border, so I used the method described in the article stated above. 
It solves the problem, but in my case it is important to have this table with 100% width.

In this case the the usage of

```
display: inline-block
```

does not allow the TH and TD elements to occupy all the width of the table.
Please, check: http://jsfiddle.net/plz007/ZFYvq/33/

So the solution from the previous article does work in IE, but only without the

```
width: 100%
```

statement.
Can you please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the table in a div/span with inline-block?

Comment: if you can, specify width in % for td's to occupy full space

Comment: The table will be generated by a script and different number of columns can be generated. I am affraid I cannot afford to have different sizes of columns each time.

Comment: Maybe there is anothe way to solve the "bleedning background cell" problem, apart from the "inline-block" method? In Chrome and FF it is enough to have overflow: hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFYvq/37/)

You're better off wrapping the table in a `div` with:

```
div{
    border-top-right-radius: 1em; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

By setting the `display` property for the table to anything other than `table` you are breaking the specific layout rules which apply to `table` elements, which will produce often unforseen issues.

nb. To remove the thick border at the bottom of the table, add `border-bottom:none;` to the `div` class